# How to disable keys from the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have a laptop with a full keyboard (it has numpad), but the laptop is not that big, and because of that the keys are relatively small, which means I am constantly finding myself pressing keys accidentally on the numpad part.

Is there a way to disable specific keys that I simply don't want?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have the `Menu` key very close to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> keys.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 135 = 0x0000'
```

To get a first impression what keycodes are mapped to which keys, just type:

```
xmodmap -pke
```

which gives you a list of all mappings. For example, the line

```
keycode  57 = n N
```

means that the keycode 57 is mapped to a lowercase "n" if no extra key is pressed, and an uppercase "N" if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is held.

Some references to get around with things.

1. **`xev`** will let you identify the keycode for your key of interest.
   Look at its man page, This is a good quick reference too,
   [Mediakeys with .Xmodmap HOWTO](http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/allinone.html)
2. ArchWiki has a good description for [**xmodmap**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Comment: what can I do to disable '/' key?

Comment: Is there any way to reset all keys if i messed up?

Answer (score 28):

**Example to disable/enable backspace:**

```
# Disable
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = '

# Enable
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = BackSpace'
```

where 22 needs to be replaced by the output of `xev` while pressing backspace.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'm always hitting "Insert" by mistake when I hit the End key, and I just remapped Insert to the End function :)

Comment: Thanks, I finally turned off some annoying touch buttons in carbon x1 ;)