# How can I childproof the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, keyboard-layout

How could I make the keyboard/touchpad safe for my toddler to use on my laptop? (e.g. allow numbers and letters but disable <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, touchpad, click events, etc). I have read [How to disable keys from the keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54417/how-to-disable-keys-from-the-keyboard), but that does not discuss everything. I am wondering if there is a pre-existing solution so that I do not need to work through all of those details myself.

I would like to be able to press a "secret set of keys" and then switch between "safe" keyboard mode and "normal" keyboard mode. I would like to do this so that I can use my keyboard, then my child may type on the keyboard, and then I can continue using the keyboard.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

```
$ uname --kernel-release --kernel-version --machine
3.2.0-56-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 09:20:45 UTC 2013 x86_64
```

Comment: You should probably make your toddler an own user account where she/he can not cause any damage, and where you can easily reset things.

Comment: Let the toddler play with the keyboard when the system is turned off. It gets boring faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid there isn't a pre-existing solution.

For the "secret key combination", see [gnome icon] → Control Center → Key Combinations.  Really, anything with a control-key+letter will probably be safe from a toddler.

For disabling keys, xmodmap is probably your best bet.  Here's how to set F1..F3 to print period or the corresponding number depending on the "shift" state...

```
xmodmap <<EOX -
keycode 67 = period 1
keycode 68 = period 2
keycode 69 = period 3
EOX
```

(that way they do "something", just nothing funny).

And this is fine for "small child comes along, wants to play with keyboard".  As they get older, they'll need their own account.

Answer (score 0):

The touchpad is easy to disable.  In system settings under "Mouse and Touchpad" under the Touchpad tab just disable it.  For the keyboard there may be a way to do what you want in software, but I've never seen or heard of it.  The trouble you're going to have is with the "secret code" to re-enable things.  The only way I can think of to re-enable the keys is with the command prompt, which you don't want to expose to the toddler.

I think a hardware approach might work better.  They sell keyboards without function keys just for kids.  For example:

[http://www.amazon.com/DURAGADGET-Colourful-Childrens-Special-Keyboard/dp/B005GL0PXK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GL0PXK)

It does still have the "esc" key.  So if you wanted to avoid that you may have to physically remove the key.  But I suppose if you're asking about a laptop (I'm assuming since you mention a touchpad) that becomes a bit difficult because you can't really remove the keyboard it comes with.

Have you seen the OLPC?  http://one.laptop.org/

They make very sturdy tablets and laptops for kids.  You can find them on ebay for relatively cheap.  Alternatively just create an account with very limited rights and if they mess it up just delete and recreate the account.