# How to disable specific key in keyboard at the lower level?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

Am using Ubuntu 14.04. My keyboard is acting strangely. The Mail button keeps pressing. I tried the things from the following links:

[1] [How to disable keys from the keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54417/how-to-disable-keys-from-the-keyboard)
[2] https://superuser.com/questions/775785/how-to-disable-a-keyboard-key-in-linux-ubuntu

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 163='
xmodmap -e 'keycode 163=NoSymbol'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 163=0x0000'
```

It does prevent the key from invoking the mail application, but the key press/release events still continue (could be seen from xev). Because of this, sometimes I am not able to make mouse selections (in nautilus), and in terminal the pointer blinks very fast.

I tried cleaning the keyboard, but it was in vain. Took out the button and the reseated it, but that didn't work as well.

Can I disable the keypress for the Mail key at the lower level, so that the key press/release events does not reach the applications?