# Disable/enable a keyboard key from the command line?

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I am looking for a way to disable/enable a specific key (e.g. backspace) from the command line.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: `setxkbd` command is frequently suggested. Your question quite well can be a duplicate since there is multitude of questions on the site about disabling keys

Comment: This one, for instance: http://askubuntu.com/q/54417/295286