# How to disable the arrow keys in Google Chrome, while watching Youtube videos, on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, xorg, google-chrome, youtube, remapping

This question is very specific, so let me explain and bear with me:

I want to disable a user from accidentally skipping content while watching YouTube movies on an instance of Google Chrome on Ubuntu. For this, I want to disable the right arrow key for a specific user.

*Note: I understand that this technique is easily to circumvent by using the mouse, but for simplicity I just want to prevent skipping by key presses.*

I have [read about the Xmodmap here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54417/how-to-disable-keys-from-the-keyboard), and this [Mediakeys with .Xmodmap HOWTO](http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/allinone.html). My file is like this:

```
keycode 114 =
```

**Simple as that, and it works, except for YouTube movies.** I works in all the OS windows, in the URL toolbar of Chrome, textareas like this question's editor box, but not for the video player. It seems, that Google Chrome's video player uses a different, more direct keyboard input source the the x window system.

So this is the question:

**How to disable the arrow keys (content skipping by keyboard) in Google Chrome, while watching YouTube videos, on Ubuntu.**

Comment: This is a bit like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer. A better solution would be to write a small JavaScript extension for Chrome, which blocks the keybinding support on YouTube.

Comment: You could probably do this by installing Vimium, disabling all the default keybindings, and setting up a no-op keybinding for the right arrow key.